# Bash redirection: can't figure why "<" and "|" doesn't work

Tags: bash, redirect, terminal

I'm studying Bash redirection, but I can't figure out how to properly use the "<" operator and the "|" (pipe) operator. I read that both will pass some information as the *input* to another program. The "<" operator will pass the content of a *file* as the *input* to a program/command and the "|" operator will pass the *stdout* of one program to another program/command, right? Here is an example, I'm trying to pass a directory I would like to be listed as the input to **ls**, but it's not working:

```
$ cat test.txt
/home/renatov/Downloads 
$ ls < test.txt 
[it lists the current folder, not /home/renatov/Downloads folder]
```

And with pipe operator:

```
$ echo '/home/renatov/Downloads' | ls 
[again, it lists the current folder, not /home/renatov/Downloads folder]
```

Where is the flaw in my reasoning? Why **ls** won't accept these contents as inputs? What am I doing wrong with Bash redirection operators?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redirection and pipes make use of stdout and stdin. Specifically, the `<` will change a process's stdin to be a file descriptor for the right-hand argument.

However, `ls` doesn't read from stdin! It only takes arguments on the command line. Because `ls` doesn't read from stdin, there is no way to use redirection.

Comment: Thanks, this clear things up! One more question: how do I know which commands read stdin and which don't?

Answer (score 1):

You need the xargs function :

```
fred:/tmp$ cat > test.txt
/tmp/test2.txt
/tmp/tmpDir
fred:/tmp$ touch test2.txt
fred:/tmp$ mkdir tmpDir
fred:/tmp$ touch tmpDir/test{1..3}.txt
fred:/tmp$ cat test.txt | xargs ls
/tmp/test2.txt

/tmp/tmpDir:
test1.txt  test2.txt  test3.txt
```

Comment: As chrisaycock pointed out, `ls` doesn't read from stdin. `xargs` is a way to do that: it reads items from the standard input (in your case lines from your file `/home/renatov/Downloads`) and executes its argument (a command - in this case `ls`) followed by item.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like

```
ls $(echo '/home/renatov/Downloads')
```

or as in your first example

```
ls $(cat test.txt)
```